# Know of SSO turnkey Appliance with ldap, radius, openid, etc?

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, appliance

I'm helping a typical small company that started with a couple of outsourced systems (google apps, svn/trac). added an internal jabber server (ejabber for mostly iChat clients). subscribes to a couple of webservices (e.g. highrisehq). and has a vpn service provided by a pfsense freebsd firewall.

And the net result of all this is that they're drowning in passwords and accounts.

It seems that if they had a single unified login / single signon service they could go a long way to combining these. E.g.:  ldap as the master repository, radius linked to it for vpn, ejabber and even WPA2 wireless access, plugins for google app sign on, and perhaps an openid server for external websites like highrisehq.

It seems that all these tools exist separately, but does anyone know of a single box that combines them with a nice GUI and auto-updates?  (e.g. like pfsense/m0n0wall for firewalls, freeNAS for storage). It doesn't have to be FOSS. A paid box would be fine too.

I figure this must exist. Microsoft's Active Directory is likely one solution but they'd rather avoid Windows if possible. There seem to be various "AAA" servers that ISPs use or for enterprise firewall/router management, but that doesn't seem quite right.

Any obvious solutions I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Perhaps this should be moved to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: Perhaps. This question preceded the existence of Server Fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been over a year since you originaly asked the question, so I'm guessing you've solved your problem by now. But if someone else is interested in a possible solution I suggest the following:

First of all, I don't know of any "all in one" solution to your problem. However it's quite easy to combine three products that will solve all of your needs and provide a single source for User management and password storage.

The first thing to do is install an LDAP Directory to manage Users and Groups (and possibly other objects outside the scope of your question). This can be [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/), [Apache DS](http://directory.apache.org/), Microsoft Active Directory, etc. Basically any LDAP Server will do.

Second I recommend installing [FreeRADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) with the [LDAP Directory configured](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-radius/) as it's backend Service.

Third get a license of [Atlassian Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/). It provides OpenID and Google Apps authentication. Prices for up to 50 Users start at $10 and go all the way up to $8000 for an unlimited user license.

Installation and Configuration of the three is relatively easy. You'll probably put most work into creating your Users and Groups. You can install all three components on a single Server and end up with a box that allows you to authenticate pretty much everything from Desktop Login, over Google Apps and other Web Apps, down to VPN and even Switch, WiFi and Router Login.

Just make sure you configure your Roles and Groups wisely! Otherwise you might end up with some Sales Person being able to do administration on your Firewalls and Routers :-)

Comment: Nope, the problem isn't solved. They just stumbled on with a mix of passwords. Recent new blood in the ops group has added an Apple server into the mix and are combining everything using the Apple-wrapped LDAP Directory and some custom scripts. So far the Jabber, internal Linux server logins, WiFi and VPN are integrated.

Comment: I just marked this as "the answer". However, it seems there is no single appliance. I wonder if this is still "An Opportunity", or a need that has been passed by.

Answer (score 3):

I would encourage anyone searching for this type of solution to check out the Gluu Server (http://gluu.org).

Each Gluu Server includes a SAML IDP for SAML SSO, an OpenID Connect Provider (OP) for OpenID Connect SSO, an UMA Policy Decision Point (PDP) for web access management, and a RADIUS and LDAP server.

All the components of the Gluu Server are open source (i.e. Shibboleth, OX, FreeRADIUS, OpenDJ, etc.), including the oxTrust web user interface for managing each component of the server.

For commercial implementations, Gluu will build, support, and monitor this stack of software on a clients VM.

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to standardise passwords across so many apps (especially external ones), though for internal ones using an auth service like LDAP makes sense.

You could solve the issue of remembering passwords with an eSSO like [Novell SecureLogin](http://www.novell.com/products/securelogin/media.html)

Also you might be interested in  [Novell Access Manager](http://www.novell.com/products/accessmanager/) and [Novell Identity Manager](http://www.novell.com/products/identitymanager/)

Answer (score 1):

I too could use such a device, however the only one I could find was a (possibly outdated) data sheet from Infoblox.  They seem to have since concentrated on automated network managment and I can't find the LDAP appliance on their current website.  I guess building a linux box with the FOSS stuff mentioned above is what everyone does, but it would be great not to have power supplies, disks, fans etc. I suppose you could use something like an EEE PC and put the config on a flash card.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I was looking for as well, and http://www.turnkeylinux.org/openldap looks like the solution: "appliance" installation, and it includes encrypted online backup which is easily restored to a new or replacement machine.